Generating the most likely random draws without sorting
Let's say I have a deck of coloured cards, and I know how many cards of each colour there are. I want to draw $n$ of them (without replacement). I want to make a list of the first $k$ most likely draws (or, even in an ideal world, have a way of generating the $k$-th most likely draw). We do not care about the order that the cards are drawn in.
An easy way to do this would be to simply generate all possible draws of $n$, and then rank them by probability, and take the first $k$. However, this becomes unfeasible when there are potentially millions of different colours and you're drawing a large amount of them. Is there a way to avoid this and somehow calculate directly the ones that are the most likely?

Does $5$ blue and $3$ green count as the same pattern as $5$ green and $3$ blue?

It is not instantly obvious.  Take Bridge: the deck has $52$ cards with $13$ cards of each of the $4$ suits, and each player is dealt $13$ cards.  Can you intuitively guess the most likely distributions of a player's hand, such as $5+4+2+2$?  Then compare your guesses to those stated at the end of this answer to another question

@Henry no. I'll update the question to clarify

Order was not quite my initial question.  I was asking about whether particular colours matter (in my Bridge example whether a $5+4+2+2$ split counts as the same pattern as $2+4+5+2$).

@Henry there isn't necessarily the same amount of each colour. Those patterns would quite likely have different probabilities.

I would take from that comment that you also regard them as different patterns.
